# YouTube parameter to call split view for 360 degree video

Tags: video, parameters, youtube, youtube-api, google-cardboard

I'm trying to find out if the "VR mode" with two eye splitview of some [YouTube 360 videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzuqhhs6NWbgTzMuM09WKDQ) can also be called via a parameter or via the API?

Right now when playing back a [#360](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ME_T4B1rxCg) video on my iPhone I'm able to move around in 360 degrees but the splitview is not an option.

If I do the same thing on an Android Device I have an option to enter "splitview" for [Google Cardboard](https://www.google.com/get/cardboard/).

Is it possible to trigger this splitview mode also from the iPhone or if a #360 video is embedded into a website with a parameter or via the API?

Comment: There is nothing in the documentation about 360 videos. 360 videos are not yet supported by Youtube API. Let us hope that there will be a Youtube 360 API. Best thing that can be done for now is to file a feature request.

Comment: Do you have a single direct page link to a video with "two eye split view" option? The random few I tried on your shown channel link didnt show that option on Windows Chrome browser. Dont know if I just picked wrong ones or just my computer. Also I hope Google's Android OS is not being favoured with features over rival's iOS when it comes to handling Google's Youtube...

Comment: The splitview has more to do with 3D then 360 I think. Google removed a lot of the options for 3D in their latest player. One of the few things that still work is replace the ?v= for /v/. E.g.: https://www.youtube.com/v/AAw_wmxV3so
Here you can change 3D options to a splitview, but this player again doesnt support 360...

Comment: Don't forget to come back, award the bounty, and accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [YouTube Help Docs](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6239930?hl=en), Google Cardboard split screen playback is only available on Android through the official YouTube app.  It is not available on iPhone or embedded videos with the iFrame API.

Android (notice the cardboard icon):

[image: android]

iOS (no cardboard icon to enable split screen video):

[image: ios]

There are known [defects and enhancements](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=label%3AAPi-YouTube%20360&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&cells=tiles) to 360 degree video playback on mobile, and full functionality and support for these types of videos on mobile is on YouTube's roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's impossible. You need to use third party app.

Google has been slow in general when it comes to rolling out support for the iPad’s headlining features. Users are still unable to view videos with the official YouTube app using the handy Picture in Picture mode, not to mention Split View.

The good news is that there are iPad apps available that allow you to enjoy YouTube videos with both Split View and Picture and Picture support in tow. In fact, CornerTube and YouPlayer are two helpful apps that come to mind. CornerTube focuses primarily on Picture in Picture mode, and YouPlayer is an outright replacement for the YouTube app, bringing Split View, Picture in Picture mode and other handy features to the fore.